# Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature during product installation

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

I tried to install a specific product but I encounter a problem that I don't understand.
Context :

- Have install this product on an Azure VM without any problems
- Same install (with same parameters) on an On-Premise HyperV VM and got errors

Try to understand and take some logs : it's a call ti java command which return an error. This error was "Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature". I'm not an expert with cipher, SSL, TLS etc. so I asked for help because I don't understand and I'm very disappointed.

Here is the log (error at the end) :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe" -cp "C:\Program Files\OpenText\Exstream\16.6\Server\lib\*";"C:\Temp\Exstream\Bootstrap-16.6.3\bin\birger.jar" -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose com.streamserve.birger.Birger SANDBOX 28800 "C:\ManagementGateway\16.6\root" SANDBOX tenantadmin@strs.role S!tr_s21!_SANDBOX "C:\Temp\Exstream\Bootstrap-16.6.3\config\tenantconfig.json" "C:\Temp\Exstream\Bootstrap-16.6.3" "C:\Program Files\OpenText\Exstream" 300000 "DUMMY" 16.6 16.6.3 SANDBOX
Working Directory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - mgw host: SANDBOX
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - mgw port: 28800
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - mgw root: C:\ManagementGateway\16.6\root
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - tenant name: SANDBOX
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - tenant admin: tenantadmin@strs.role
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - tenant admin pwd: **********************
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - tenant config file: C:\Temp\Exstream\Bootstrap-16.6.3\config\tenantconfig.json
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - bootstrap folder: C:\Temp\Exstream\Bootstrap-16.6.3
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - strs installdir: C:\Program Files\OpenText\Exstream
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - mgw timeout: 300000
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - build number: DUMMY
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - strs version: 16.6
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - strsfileversion: 16.6.3
13:13:25.162 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - virtualhost: SANDBOX
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:25.302 WAT|SSLCipher.java:437|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
13:13:25.458 [main] INFO com.streamserve.birger.Birger - runCommand executing: [C:\Program Files\OpenText\Exstream\16.6\Server\bin\\ss_territory.exe, -action, display_node_info, -cert, C:\Program Files\OpenText\Exstream\16.6\Server\global\security\certificatestore\trusted\authorities\demo.crt, -host, SANDBOX, -ipport, 28800, -user, SANDBOX\tenantadmin@strs.role, -pass, S!tr_s21!_SANDBOX, -timeout, 300000]
13:13:25.583 [main] INFO com.streamserve.birger.Birger - Displayname: SANDBOX
Node ID: EDEE078A-5FC4-4D83-9B6E-948D95F52A86
Lastheartbeattime: 2023-08-31T07:54:02.123Z
Platform: windows
IP: SANDBOX
IPPort: 28800
Description: StreamServe Management Gateway
Version: 16.6.3 GA

13:13:25.583 [main] INFO com.streamserve.birger.Birger - Displayname: SANDBOX
Node ID: EDEE078A-5FC4-4D83-9B6E-948D95F52A86
Lastheartbeattime: 2023-08-31T07:54:02.123Z
Platform: windows
IP: SANDBOX
IPPort: 28800
Description: StreamServe Management Gateway
Version: 16.6.3 GA

..................

13:13:26.240 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - Creating domain: SANDBOX
13:13:26.240 [main] DEBUG com.streamserve.birger.Birger - Converting resource name [SANDBOX] to [SANDBOX] !
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.240 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS12
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.240 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS12
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.255 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.271 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|HandshakeContext.java:290|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|ServerNameExtension.java:255|Unable to indicate server name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.287 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:235|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.302 WAT|SignatureScheme.java:358|Ignore disabled signature sheme: rsa_md5
javax.net.ssl|INFO|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.318 WAT|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.318 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:235|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.318 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:235|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.318 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:235|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.318 WAT|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:606|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.318 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:235|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.318 WAT|ClientHello.java:633|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "75 C7 1A 11 23 B8 00 A5 FF B3 5E 43 4D 88 5F F7 5A B7 F2 37 36 B0 5B 69 6B 24 48 35 34 FC ED 59",
  "session id"          : "3A 99 B5 D5 37 A6 67 5A 87 0A 6C BE D7 19 5B B0 53 D7 B7 4E 39 BF 53 48 CD 0D AB E0 C5 DB 20 04",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp512r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp512r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 CD 72 A7 76 A2 61 43   08 B7 05 BE 99 D7 87 BD  ..r.v.aC........
            0010: 92 64 15 8F 81 55 84 02   DA BD A5 FC 34 F9 7A 52  .d...U......4.zR
            0020: C6 1C EC 83 FD 15 E8 92   51 DD 88 8E 59 1C E8 C4  ........Q...Y...
            0030: DE 36 E7 75 88 11 79 80   C6 0D 25 B8 81 DA 33 23  .6.u..y...%...3#
            0040: DF
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|ServerHello.java:866|Consuming ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "D7 0C D7 65 0E 60 52 A9 E4 3D 8B 7B BE D7 3A 6D AA 5D 2D AB 04 88 34 BD E9 8B C3 7A DE 78 89 87",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed, ansiX962_compressed_prime, ansiX962_compressed_char2]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:148|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|ServerHello.java:962|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:167|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:148|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:148|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:148|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:167|Consumed extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:148|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:138|Ignore unsupported extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:138|Ignore unsupported extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:167|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:138|Ignore unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:190|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.349 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.365 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.365 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.365 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:190|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.365 WAT|SSLExtensions.java:182|Ignore unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.365 WAT|CertificateMessage.java:358|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v1",
    "serial number"      : "0B",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA1withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "O=StreamServe, C=SE, ST=ShouldBeIgnored, CN=ShouldBeIgnored",
    "not before"         : "2007-01-08 09:37:42.000 WAT",
    "not  after"         : "2027-02-20 09:37:42.000 WAT",
    "subject"            : "CN=ShouldBeIgnored, O=StreamServe, C=SE",
    "subject public key" : "RSA"}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.380 WAT|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ECDHServerKeyExchange$ECDHServerKeyExchangeMessage.<init>(ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:329)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ECDHServerKeyExchange$ECDHServerKeyExchangeConsumer.consume(ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:535)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerKeyExchange$ServerKeyExchangeConsumer.consume(ServerKeyExchange.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1356)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1331)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:241)
        at com.streamserve.birger.Birger.wsSendResourceRequest(Birger.java:723)
        at com.streamserve.birger.Birger.checkCasObject(Birger.java:888)
        at com.streamserve.birger.Birger.CreateDomains(Birger.java:1916)
        at com.streamserve.birger.Birger.main(Birger.java:2787)}

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.380 WAT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1361|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2023-08-31 13:13:26.380 WAT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1380|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ECDHServerKeyExchange$ECDHServerKeyExchangeMessage.<init>(ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:329)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ECDHServerKeyExchange$ECDHServerKeyExchangeConsumer.consume(ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:535)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerKeyExchange$ServerKeyExchangeConsumer.consume(ServerKeyExchange.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1356)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1331)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:241)
        at com.streamserve.birger.Birger.wsSendResourceRequest(Birger.java:723)
        at com.streamserve.birger.Birger.checkCasObject(Birger.java:888)
        at com.streamserve.birger.Birger.CreateDomains(Birger.java:1916)
        at com.streamserve.birger.Birger.main(Birger.java:2787)
ERROR:  'Premature end of file.'
ao¹t 31, 2023 1:13:26 PM com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory parseEnvelopeSax
SEVERE: SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source
13:13:26.693 [main] ERROR com.streamserve.birger.Birger - Exit: Failed to check if domain exists
13:13:26.693 [main] INFO com.streamserve.birger.Birger - Domain [SANDBOX] already exists with id [null]
13:13:26.693 [main] ERROR com.streamserve.birger.Birger - Domain creation failed!
```

Hope this community could help me.

Regards.

Cédric

Install on Azure VM : OK
Install on On-premise HyperV VM : KO